# Basic hotkeys and shortcuts not working?

Tags: kde, 17.04

I just installed KDE desktop on Ubuntu 17.04 and to my dismay hotkeys like the windows key and shortcuts like alt-tab are not working. How can I fix it?

Comment: What was the exact command you used to install "KDE desktop"? Have you logged out and logged back in after installing it?

Comment: I used the **kde-desktop** package to install it. And yes I rebooted before entering KDE as I also had upgrade my kernel

Comment: I would have gone for `kubuntu-desktop` but do that only if you have Synaptic Package Manager installed to troubleshoot any issues.